# What does Default of Haskell mean?

Tags: haskell

I am currently working on a function in Haskell that needs to do the following:

> Declare the type and define a function that takes 3 numbers as input and checks if they are all different. Please give 3 versions of it. First use if else mechanism, then use guards, and third one use default of Haskell

I have completed it with if-else, and guards, but I don't know what "Default of Haskell" means? I'm not looking for anyone to do my work for me, but if someone could just clear up what I need to do, that would be great.

Thank you very much.

Comment: My guess is that it is missing a word and they meant to say "default functions of Haskell".

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It sounds like the author's grasp of English was failing him.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so it just means that I can do it in anyway?

Comment: No, it means you should ask your professor what he meant.

Comment: I second Alexey's comment (you should ask your professor) but I expect that s/he means "using built-in functions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **default** means using just comparison operators.

```
different1 a b c = if a == b then False else if a == c then False else if b == c then False else True
different2 a b c| a == b    = False
                | b == c    = False
                | a == c    = False
                | otherwise = True
different3 a b c = a /= b && b /= c && a /= c
```